# How to enable and set the time interval of autosave in preference through code

Tags: eclipse-plugin

How to enable the Editors->Autosave preference button and time interval programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API for this.

Looking at `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.AutoSavePreferencePage` which deals with this preference the values are stored in the preferences for the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plug-in.

So something like:

```java
IPreferenceStore prefs = 
    new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "org.eclipse.ui.workbench");

prefs.setValue("SAVE_AUTOMATICALLY", true);

prefs.setValue("SAVE_AUTOMATICALLY_INTERVAL", interval (as a string));
```

`org.eclipse.ui.internal.IPreferenceConstants` contains constants for the preference keys but since this is an internal class it should not be used.

Note: Since this is not an official API it may change at any time.

Comment: If the preference type is combo how to set the combo value?

Comment: @Nav That depends on the code for the particular combo. There is no general answer. Ask a question about the specific setting or read the source code.